# Need discontinuous numbering of subfigures in \subfigure[]

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I have 8 subfigures in each figure. I need 4 in each row. Based on a suggestion I found on this site, I have ordered it like this:

```
\documentstyle[psfig,eepic,epic,subfigure,pdflscape,natbib,amsbsy,graphicx,graphics,enumerate,multirow,amstext,mathrsfs,12pt,float]{strthestp}
\textwidth 5.0in
\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.9in}
\pagestyle{itulheadings}
\bibliographystyle{elsart-harv}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l0_ten}} \label{phi_l0_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l0p5_ten}} \label{phi_l0p5_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l1_ten}} \label{phi_l1_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l2_ten}} \label{phi_l2_ten} 

    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l3_ten}} \label{phi_l3_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l5_ten}} \label{phi_l5_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l10_ten}} \label{phi_l10_ten} 
    \subfigure[]
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 479,clip]{\kawFigPath chap5fig_new/phi_l25_ten}} \label{phi_l25_ten}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
because, if i use `\begin{subfigure} \end{subfigure}`, the last fig in the second row goes to the third one.
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l0_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l0p5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l1_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l2_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l3_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l10_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 479,clip]{ten_figs/phi_l25_ten}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l0_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l0p5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l1_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l2_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l3_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l10_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 479,clip]{ten_figs/gp_l25_ten}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l0_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l0p5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l1_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l2_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l3_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l10_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 479,clip]{ten_figs/loglp_l25_ten}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l0_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l0p5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l1_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l2_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l3_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l5_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 359,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l10_ten}} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
      {\includegraphics[width=66mm,angle = -90,viewport = 16 72 594 479,clip]{ten_figs/coh_l25_ten}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem with `\subfigure[]` is that the numbering between two figures is continued - e.g.: in fig 1 it goes from a-h, and the second fig. starts from i-p and so on. But I need the second figure to go from 2(a)-2(h). How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited my post to make it a MWE. hope u can help me!

Comment: Are your *really* using documentstyle? It is deprecated for 20 years. Also, where can one find the documentclass you are using?

Comment: I just wonder if it would be helpful to say that subfigure is deprecated for a while as well. Usage of package `subcaption` is recommended.

Comment: The wise google bot just gave me: https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/jeet.sty

Comment: I saw that you have been online since. Can you give us some feedback? Right now, nobody can poost an answer to a system that is obsolete for 20 years using packages that are obsolete as well. A few more information would be fine.